# google drive sdk for ios queryForFilesList,can not get file list

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I modify or create a file using web interface or using local drive client for mac os. These file are not shown in my application.

even I Changed the scope in method `authButtonClicked` of `DrEditFilesListViewController.m`

Replace this scope  `kGTLAuthScopeDriveFile` with `kGTLAuthScopeDrive` as follow

```
GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *authViewController = 
  [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:kGTLAuthScopeDriveFile
                                             clientID:kClientId
                                         clientSecret:kClientSecret
                                     keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                                             delegate:self
                                     finishedSelector:finishedSelector];
```

to

```
GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *authViewController = 
  [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:kGTLAuthScopeDrive
                                             clientID:kClientId
                                         clientSecret:kClientSecret
                                     keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                                             delegate:self
                                     finishedSelector:finishedSelector];
```

I get file list as fowllow:

```
GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];
query.q = @"mimeType = 'text/plain'";
    [self.driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                              GTLDriveFileList *files,
                                                              NSError *error) {

 ......
    }];
```

Comment: Any error or something which you get would be helpful ...!
Try putting debugger in the delegate methods to check if control reaches them and inspect for error code if any and inform about it here.

Comment: there is no error.the delegate methods come back is successful.I creat a file in my app and save it,I can see it in the web interface.

Comment: I use is an example of an official.